# I am getting Error "Secure 3d is not configured for version Two"

Tags: global-payments-api

I am try to implement 3d secure V2, but when I try to call the method

```
Secure3dService.CheckEnrollment(cardData).Execute(Secure3dVersion.Two)
```

I am getting error for "Secure 3d is not configured for version Two." Any one has idea about the error?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for the above error. While configuring the 3d secure V2 in ServiceContainer do not select Secure3dVersion = Secure3dVersion.Two. I dont know but global payment api not support the Secure3dVersion.Two in the configuiration.

Below is my configuration settings

```
ServicesContainer.ConfigureService(new GpEcomConfig
            {
                MerchantId = MerchantId,
                //AccountId = "ecom3ds",
                AccountId = "3dsv2",
                SharedSecret = SharedSecret,
                ServiceUrl = V2ServiceUrl,
                ChallengeNotificationUrl = "https://www.example.com/challengeNotificationUrl",
                //MethodNotificationUrl = "https://www.example.com/methodNotificationUrl",
                MethodNotificationUrl = "https://localhost:44345/ThreeDSecureNotification.aspx",
                Secure3dVersion = Secure3dVersion.Any
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

we also included these

```
      HostedPaymentConfig = new HostedPaymentConfig
        {
            Version = "2"
        },
        Secure3dVersion = Secure3dVersion.Two,
```